# MySQL Query to Fetch Members New Position From different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the Members New Rank Earned from two tables( Excluding members with same rank and null Values ). I have already tried a lot of queries but they returning all member's list and null.

```sql
 SELECT m.member_id, m.rank_id old_rank_id, 
        IF( mp.tpc_x > mp.tpc_y,mp.tpc_y, mp.tpc_x ) as pairs, 
        ( 
           SELECT p.rank_id 
           FROM performance_bonus p 
           LEFT JOIN member m ON p.rank_id = m.rank_id 
           WHERE pairs >= p.pairs_count AND pairs <= p.max_pairs 
        ) as new_rank_id 
 FROM member_post mp 
 LEFT JOIN `member` m ON mp.member_id = m.member_id
```

Table: member ( by default `rank_id` is 0, need to find the `new_rank_id` )

```
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| member_id   | member_name    | rank_id               |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
| 10000       | XYZ            | 0                     |
| 10001       | YSA            | 0                     |
+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Table: member_post ( Finding pairs of Post or simply finding min value between tpc_x and tpc_y becomes `pairs_count` or `max_pairs` of `performance_bonus` table )

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| member_id   | tpc_x          | tpc_y    |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 10000       | 150            | 100      |
| 10001       | 300            | 200      |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
```

Table: performance_bonus ( `max_pairs` is that a member should be in between `pairs_count` AND `max_pairs` to get the Achievement Name )

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| rank_id   | rank_name  | pairs_count    | max_pairs   |
+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1         | Student    | 100            | 199         |
| 2         | Teacher    | 200            | 399         |
+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Edit:
 Edited some descriptions.

Demo Result: ( Null because no ranks Exist above that `rank_id` )

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
+ member_id   | old_rank_id | new_rank_id   |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 10000       | 0           | 1             |
| 10001       | 0           | 2             |
| 10002       | 4           | 3             |
| 10003       | 5           | null          |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
+ member_id   | old_rank_id | new_rank_id   |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 10000       | 0           | 1             |
| 10001       | 0           | 2             |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Can you show the desired result for the given data?

Comment: I have edited some descriptions above and also added Demo Result that i am getting and expected result. Thanks

Comment: I guess that you want to filter out records with `old_rank_id <> 0`. Since `old_rank_id` is an alias for `m.rank_id`, then use `WHERE m.rank_id = 0` at the end of the query.